# Java: What's the benefit of using full class path rather than "import"?

Tags: java

Recently I am working with a simple Java web app project (jetty 9).

It somehow confused me since rather than using `import`, it uses full class path everywhere, like:

```
@java.lang.Override
private void someAction(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest req, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse resp) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    javax.servlet.http.HttpSession sess = req.getSession(false);
    if(sess==null){
        ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)resp).sendError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

even for simple `Int` or `String`.

I know `import` with wildcard should be avoided, but is there any advantage / benefit by dropping `import` completely?

Comment: The only use case I can think of is if you use two classes with the same simple name (e.g. `foo.bar.MyClass` and `frob.nitz.MyClass`), where you need to fully-qualify at least one of the names; otherwise, it's just more code to use the fully-qualified name; imports are merely a syntactic convenience.

Comment: It's also a bit easier if you are generating code to use the FQ name, since you don't need to keep track of classes you need to import: you can just generate the code with the FQ name in it already, and not generate an imports block at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the benefit is that you make the compiler happy since, by stating the full class path, you automatically avoid the ambiguity issue with may occur when you use the wild card.
However then you have have to type more, but I think Jetty auto-Generates this code so, it's no big deal if you are generating the code.